# Prevent Fancybox from happening on disabled images

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm making a site with a grid of photos that are "filterable." I am calling fancybox with:

```
$(".popbox").fancybox();
```

When an image is filtered out, it gets a class of "disabled."  Note, the page is not reloaded.

```
<a class="popbox disabled" style="opacity: 0.3;">
<img alt="placeholder" src="_assets/images/placeholder.jpg">
</a>
```

How can I make it so when someone clicks a disabled image, fancybox will not activate?  I also need it to work again when the filter is changed and the image is re-enabled.

Comment: Put the `fancybox()` call in a `click()` and check if it's got a class `disabled`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ANLxC/)):

```
$(function() {
    $('.popbox').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).is('.disabled')){
            $.fancybox('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" height="333" width="500">');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Update: And here is probably a better way to do it, using the `onStart` callback ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ANLxC/1/)):

```
$(function() {
    $('.popbox').fancybox({
        onStart: function(link) {
            if ($(link).is('.disabled')) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, give this a go:

```
$('.popbox:not(.disabled)').fancybox();
```